# Value of the Riemann Zeta Function for negative integers

Tags: proof-explanation, contour-integration, riemann-zeta, bernoulli-numbers

I am reading the book **"Riemann's Zeta Function"** by *H. M. Edwards*. I had a confusion in *Section 1.5, Page 12* at the derivation of the formula of Riemann Zeta Function at negative integers i.e. $\zeta(-n)$ in terms of the Bernoulli numbers.
[image]

In the first step the power series expansion
$$\dfrac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{B_nx^n}{n!}$$ where $B_n$ denotes the Bernoulli Numbers, has been substituted into the formula
$$\zeta(s)=\dfrac{\Pi(-s)}{2\pi i}\int^{+\infty}_{+\infty}\dfrac{(-x)^s}{e^x-1}\dfrac{dx}{x}$$

Here $\Pi(x)=\Gamma(x+1)$.

I am not sure

1. Where the $|x|=\delta$ comes from?
2. How the variable is changed from $x$ to $\theta$?
3. How the final integral and summation is solved?

I noticed that there was already a question on this [Contour Integration, Riemann Zeta (-n)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836960/contour-integration-riemann-zeta-n?rq=1). But, this fails to clarify my doubts.

Comment: you first need to understand the original contour of integration which is formed by a line starting at infinity above the real axis, going around $0$ at radius $\delta$ and then going back to infinity under the real axis - for integral $n$ the parts on the lines above and below the real axis cancel out (see Edwards for details), so you juts remain with the integral on the circle $\delta$; there you use the Taylor series in question for $\delta$ small enough and then by residues or integration term by term and orthogonality, all but one integral from the Taylor series cancels

Comment: @Conrad I do understand the contour integration, but how is it converted into the $d\theta$ integral?

Comment: the integral on the circle $\delta$ is parametrized by the angle $\theta$ as is usually done - note that if you apply residues you do not actually need to parametrize it

Comment: @Conrad I am a bit confused. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: on the circle $\delta$ one has $x=|\delta| e^{i \theta}, dx=i |\delta| e^{i \theta} d \theta= i xd\theta$ and the integral of $x^kd\theta$ is zero unless $k=0$; so $m=n+1$

Comment: You might check out my response to the MO-Q https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58004/how-does-one-motivate-the-analytic-continuation-of-the-riemann-zeta-function/97401#97401, which essentially follows Riemann's introduction of complex analysis to characterizing the Reimann zeta.

Comment: @Conrad Thank You very much. That clarifies my problems.